# Pandas plotting - Subplotting with axed plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a few scatterplots with axes added (to color-code the output), and I'd like to put them in a matrix (subplots). However, since they're axed already, I get the error: `TypeError: inner() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ax'`, as expected, and I get 4x2 empty plots, and the other plots are just dumped under it. To show you what I mean:

```
fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2)

scatter1 = df.groupby(['Month', 'Price'])['Quantity'].sum().reset_index()
ax = scatter1[scatter1['Price'] == 460].plot(kind='scatter', x='Month', y='Quantity', color='Blue', label='230HUF');
fig1 = scatter1[scatter1['Price'] == 500].plot(kind='scatter', x = 'Month', y = 'Quantity', color='Yellow', label='250HUF', ax = ax )

scatter2 = df.groupby(['Month', 'Price'])['Quantity'].sum().reset_index()
ax = scatter2[scatter2['Price'] == 460].plot(kind='scatter', x='Month', y='Quantity', color='Blue', label='230HUF');
fig2 = scatter2[scatter2['Price'] == 500].plot(kind='scatter', x = 'Month', y = 'Quantity', color='Yellow', label='250HUF', ax = ax )

fig1.plot(figsize = (25,20),ax=axes1[0,0])
fig2.plot(figsize = (25,20),ax=axes1[0,1])
```

shows this:

[image: shows this:]

What I'd like to achieve:

[image: this]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `ax=axes1[0]` argument to the first `df.plot`call,`ax=axes1[1]` to the second, etc.

EDIT:

What you would like to do should look something like this:

*Creating some mock dataframes:*

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(rand(10,2),columns=['x column','y column'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(rand(10,2),columns=['x column','y column'])
df3=pd.DataFrame(rand(10,2),columns=['x column','y column'])
df4=pd.DataFrame(rand(10,2),columns=['x column','y column'])
```

*Creating the plots:*

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2)
df1.plot(kind='scatter',x='x column',y='y column',ax=axes[0,0])
df2.plot(kind='scatter',x='x column',y='y column',ax=axes[0,1],color='red')
df3.plot(kind='scatter',x='x column',y='y column',ax=axes[1,0],color='green')
df1.plot(kind='scatter',x='x column',y='y column',ax=axes[1,1],color='orange')
```

Which results in this plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: You mean like this: `fig1.plot(figsize = (25,20),ax=axes1[0])
fig2.plot(figsize = (25,20),ax=axes1[1])` ?

Comment: no, the other plot calls. Also I would omit the last 2 lines and set the figure size in the plt.subplots call.

Comment: @lte__ I added a working example to illustrate what I meant. BTW I was partially wrong because the axes object  return by subplots(...) is an array and not a list as I initially thought .